# Execute javascript before a //=require occurs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

Using Rails 3.2.0 with haml, sass and coffeescript:
Basically I am trying to disable jQuery_Mobile loading pages with ajax without having to include a buch of javascript within any of my views.

I tried this:

```
13 //= require jquery¬
14 //= require jquery_ujs¬
15 //= require_tree .¬
16 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {¬
17   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;¬
18 });¬
19 //= require jquery_mobile¬
```

with no success, I don't completely understand the chain of events when `= javascript_include_tag "application"¬` is called and what `// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.¬` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you put in the application.js manifest file will be executed at the bottom of that file once all other require directives have been run.

What you want is to put this code inside a javascript file (call it `jquery_mobile_startup.js`) and put a `require 'jquery_mobile_startup.js'` at the top of your file.

Sprockets honors the order you put stuff in there and require_tree will not re-import what you already imported.

To expand a bit on this:

application.js is being read as the manifest file for what files to include and when running in production Sprockets/Rails will combine all files that are required in the manifest into one big minified JavaScript file and serve that to your users. 
Only in development will the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` generate multiple  tags for you.

All require calls will generate a  tag and all regular Javascript code will be remain in application.js that gets imported after all imported files (in development).

Answer (score 1):

The `require` instruction is processed on the server side by Sprockets (the asset pipeline). Coffeescript / Sprockets won't execute any Javascript. When you use `javascript_include_tag "application"` the pipeline loads the manifest file (application.js) and process `require` statements to serve your Javascript.

In development, it will add several `<script>` markups to your view.

For production, `rake assets:precompile` allows you to ask Sprockets to compile an `application-hash.js` file (the hash value allows cache/versionning of your assets) and add a single `<script>` markup to the view.

Anyhow if you need to put Javascript code in your manifest (bad practice IMHO) you should add it after `require` directives.

If you need to avoid unnecessary Javascript to be loaded, a strategy could be to filter included files depending on the user's browser : create another JS manifest and decide which one to use depending on the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header. A simplistic example :

```
  # app/helpers/user_agent_helper.rb
  def iphone?
    request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && /iPhone/=~request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
  end

  # app/viewss/layouts/application.html.erb
  ...
  <head>
    <%= javascript_include_tag iphone? ? 'iphone' : 'application' %>
  </head>

  # app/assets/javascripts/iphone.js
  //= require jquery
  //= require jquery-mobile
  //= require your-iphone-specific-js
```